Is it likely that Paul and Barnabas preached on the Sabbath in Acts 14:1?
Paul preached in the synagogue on the Sabbath day in Acts 13:14. He was then forced out of the city and came to Iconium. It mentions that they went and preached in the synagogue in this city. How likely is it that he preached on the Sabbath day in Iconium?

Acts 13:14 - And from Perga, they traveled inland to Pisidian Antioch,
where they entered the synagogue on the Sabbath and sat down.


Acts 14:1 - At Iconium, Paul and Barnabas went as usual into the
Jewish synagogue, where they spoke so well that a great number of Jews
and Greeks believed.


As you probably know, Stack Exchange is a great place to seek objective, fact-based answers. Your question seems to be primarily opinion-based. We could argue that it's probable considering their previous practice of preaching in synagogues on the Sabbath. See verses like Acts 13:14-15,42,44. However, if the text does not say then it does not say. We would just be guessing.

I am unsure if your question is asking whether Acts 13:4 and Acts 14:1 refer to the same Sabbath day. It seems you are concerned that Paul and Barnabas might have taken too much time travelling to Iconium to arrive on the same day.

The short answer to the question is, we are not told.
However, let us examine the regular practice of Paul and the apostles as they travelled:

Acts 13:14 - And from Perga, they traveled inland to Pisidian Antioch, where they entered the synagogue on the Sabbath and sat down.
Acts 13:44 - On the following Sabbath, nearly the whole city gathered to hear the word of the Lord.
Acts 16:13 - On the Sabbath we went outside the city gate along the river, where it was customary to find a place of prayer. After sitting down, we spoke to the women who had gathered there.
Acts 17:2 - As was his custom, Paul went into the synagogue, and on three Sabbaths he reasoned with them from the Scriptures
Acts 18:4 - Every Sabbath he reasoned in the synagogue, trying to persuade Jews and Greeks alike.

In the case of Iconium we have:

Acts 14:1 - At Iconium, Paul and Barnabas went as usual into the Jewish synagogue, where they spoke so well that a great number of Jews and Greeks believed.

Now, based on Paul's practice and habit as listed above, especially Acts 17:2, it is highly likely that Paul went on the Sabbath day to the Synagogue in Iconium.  Further I also note that even in the absence of a local synagogue (as was the case in Acts 16:3) went to a "place of prayer" to observe the Sabbath.

I would appreciate your input on the term "as usual" which is omitted by many translators.

@DanFefferman - the initial phrase of Acts 17:2 is κατὰ δὲ τὸ εἰωθὸς τῷ Παύλῳ = Now, according to the custom of Paul.  All versions I checked included this phrase.  Which version have you found that omit it?

There is an important translation issue here. The OP's text says the apostles went "as usual" to the synagogue, which can easily be understood to mean they did so on the Sabbath. However, many translations omit "as usual" and substitute "together" or "both." Young's Literal Translation says:

And it came to pass in Iconium, that they did enter together into the
synagogue of the Jews, and spake, so that there believed both of Jews
and Greeks a great multitude

The question here is how to translate "κατὰ τὸ αὐτὸ" -- literally "according to the same."  Does it mean "as usual" or "together?"
Leaving that aside, verse 3 goes on to tell us that they stayed for a "considerable period." If so they must have attended Sabbath meetings as well as daily prayers and study.
Conclusion: We lack adequate information to know if their first public speech in the synagogue was on a Sabbath or not. But since they were in the city for a long time, they must have done so at some point, probably more than once.
